# Security warning on custom Preview Handler

Tags: security, ms-office, outlook-addin, preview, windows-shell

I wrote my own preview handler on .NET for Outlook 2007/2010 and XP/Vista/Windows7

When an e-mail with an attachment requires my handler to visualize it an alert says:

*"you should only preview files from a trustworthy source"*

I tried signing the EXE and the alert is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is setting this key on the registry: HKCR\Software\Microsoft\Office\Previewers\\PONTState = 1